# How do I mock local variables of a mocked class in a Spock test?

Tags: unit-testing, variables, grails, mocking, spock

Let's say I have the following method in a service:

```
private void deleteItems(List<Item> itemsToDelete) {
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    itemsToDelete?.each { Item item ->
        sql.execute("DELETE FROM owner_item WHERE item_id = ${item.id}")
        item.delete(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        flushDatabaseSession();
    }
}
```

How do I create a test for this method in the ItemServiceSpec?  When I try it, I get either a DataSource *"Must specify a non-null Connection"* error or a **nullPointerException** on sql.

This is my existing test.

```
@TestFor(ItemService)
@Mock([Item])
@Build([Item])
class SubjectServiceSpec extends Specification {

...

    def "delete items"() {
        given:
        Item item1 = Item.build().save(flush: true)
        Item item2 = Item.build().save(flush: true)
        Item.count() == 2
        DataSource mockDataSource = Mock()
        service.dataSource = mockDataSource
        1 * deleteItems

        when:
        service.deleteItems([item1, item2])

        then:
        Item.count() == 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do here, is to mock a dependency (`DataSource`) of a dependency (`Sql`). This normally leads to a situation, where you a not 100% aware of how the `Sql` interacts with the `DataSource` Object. If `Sql` changes private interaction with the `Datasource` in a Version Update, you have to deal with the situation.

Instead of mocking a dependency of a dependency you should the `Sql` Class directly. For this, the `sql` has to be some kind of explicit dependency that you can receive via DI or a method parameter. In this case you can just mock the `execute` call like so (choosen the way of a [Expando-Mock](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Developer+Testing+using+Maps+and+Expandos+instead+of+Mocks), but you could also use `Map` or the Mock Stuff from Spock):

```
given:
def sqlMock = new Expando()
sqlMock.execute = { return 'what ever you want or nothing, because you mock a delete operation' }
service.sql = sqlMock

when:
service.deleteItems([item1, item2])

then:
assertItemsAreDeletedAndTheOwnerAsWell()
```

Thinking about the whole testcase, there a two major problems in my opinion.

The first one is, when you ask yourself what kind of certainty do you really get here by mocking out the whole sql stuff. In  this case, the only thing that you are doing here is to interact with the db. When you mock this thing out, then there is nothing anymore that you could test. There is not many conditional stuff or anything that should be backed up by a unit test. Due to this, I would suggest to write only integration spec for this test-case where you have something like a H2DB for testing purposes inplace.

The second thing is, that you actually don't need the Sql Manipulation at all. You can configure GORM and Hibernate in a way do a automatic and transparent deletion of the owner of the item, if the item is deleted. For this, look at the docs (especially the [cascade part](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html)) from GORM or directly in the [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-transitive).

To sum it up: use `cascade: 'delete'` together with a proper integration test and you have a high amount of certainty and less boilerplate code.